# Arc progress bar bug - CSS, HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a circular progress bar that is 75% of it's circumference (in a shape of an arc).

The problem is that there are values that I pass to the progress function that brings the green circle out of the meter and that is what I want to avoid.

I do not understand what am I missing there.

Thank you in advance.

```js
let speedCircle = document.querySelector(".speed");

let radius = speedCircle.r.baseVal.value;

let circumference = 2 * radius * Math.PI * 0.75;

speedCircle.style.strokeDasharray = circumference;

const progress = percent => {
    speedCircle.style.strokeDashoffset = (percent / 100) * circumference;
}

progress(30);
```

```css
.speed, .meter {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 10;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.speed {
    stroke: green;
}

.meter {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-dasharray: 471.239;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="250" height="250">
    <circle r="100" cx="125" cy="125" class="meter"></circle>
    <circle r="100" cx="125" cy="125" class="speed"></circle>
</svg>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```